# Android : Circular pulsating help for the FAB button

Tags: android, interface, floating-action-button

I saw various apps using this exact interface to help their users when they use it for the first time. (Colored disc, descriptive text and the pulsating fab button). Anybody knows the name of this library? Comes it from the Android SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same ripple effect can be achieved using [TaptTargetView](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView) library.

**TapTargetView** Library

It has a very simple usage

```
TapTargetView.showFor(this,                 // `this` is an Activity
    TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.target), "This is a target", "We have the best targets, believe me")
        // All options below are optional
        .outerCircleColor(R.color.red)      // Specify a color for the outer circle
        .outerCircleAlpha(0.96f)            // Specify the alpha amount for the outer circle
        .targetCircleColor(R.color.white)   // Specify a color for the target circle
        .cancelable(false)                  // Whether tapping outside the outer circle dismisses the view
        .tintTarget(true)                   // Whether to tint the target view's color
        .transparentTarget(false)           // Specify whether the target is transparent (displays the content underneath)
        .icon(Drawable)                     // Specify a custom drawable to draw as the target
        .targetRadius(60),                  // Specify the target radius (in dp)
    new TapTargetView.Listener() {          // The listener can listen for regular clicks, long clicks or cancels
        @Override
        public void onTargetClick(TapTargetView view) {
            super.onTargetClick(view);      // This call is optional
            doSomething();
        }
    });
```

You can also perform a sequence of actions on elements

```
new TapTargetSequence(this)
    .targets(
        TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.never), "Gonna"),
        TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.give), "You", "Up")
                .dimColor(android.R.color.never)
                .outerCircleColor(R.color.gonna)
                .targetCircleColor(R.color.let)
                .textColor(android.R.color.you),
        TapTarget.forBounds(rickTarget, "Down", ":^)")
                .cancelable(false)
                .icon(rick))
    .listener(new TapTargetSequence.Listener() {
        // This listener will tell us when interesting(tm) events happen in regards
        // to the sequence
        @Override
        public void onSequenceFinish() {
            // Yay
        }

        @Override
        public void onSequenceStep(TapTarget lastTarget) {
           // Perfom action for the current target
        }

        @Override
        public void onSequenceCanceled(TapTarget lastTarget) {
            // Boo
        }
    });
```

Add this to your build.gradle

```
repositories { 
        jcenter()
   }

   dependencies {
         implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.12.0'
   }
```

Comment: No need to apologize. Your link fully answered my question.